# What is the meaning of "meant more to "?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "meant more to " in the following sentence,

> Tabby is an old yellow cat. Tabby loved Mr. Putter's tulips. She was old, and beautiful things
>   **meant more to** her.

?
 :: Source: Mr. Putter and Tabby(Pour the tea)

Does "She was old, and beautiful things meant more to her"
 mean "She was more interested in old and beautiful things (She was meant more old and beautiufl things to her)" or 
"She was old. So she was more interested in beautiful things (She was old. So she was meant more beautiful things to her)"

?

Does "beautiful things meant more to her" mean " beautiful things became more meaningful(important) to her" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It clearly states that, first of all, the cat was old. And, secondly, while it's not all that clear from the context whether this has any connection to the fact that the cat was old, beautiful things were more significant to her than any other things. In other words, as you said it yourself, she was more interested in beautiful things. That's literally all it says. No less, no more.

If it's the expression *"to mean something to somebody"* that confuses you, then it just means *"to be of a specified degree of importance to somebody"* or *"to be very valuable to somebody"*. For example:

> This old toy car means a lot to me because it was a gift on my fifth birthday from my grandfather who never came back home from the front line.

Comment: Does "it just means to be of a specified degree of importance to somebody" mean "it just means to be something of a specified degree of importance to somebody" ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the word **meants** means. By the way, can you see where the italicized text starts and where it ends?

Comment: I am sorry. I have a mistake (meant---> means). What I want to know that .......does " be of " mean " be something of " ?

Comment: Can't say. It all depends on the context.